# How to display an existing ListFragment in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, popupwindow

I have the following problem:

I have an exisiting `ListFragment`, but I would like to display this as a dialog.

My first approach was to create a `DialogFragment` which has to `ListFragment` inside of it, but appearently it is currently not possible to put fragments in fragments.

Extending `DialogFragment` instead of `ListFragment` is also not possible, because of the heavy use of `ListFragment` methods.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: I also have similar problem. And I'm surprised I cannot find answer anywhere. I think it's a common task, e.g. when you want to display full screen activity with Fragment in portrait, and the same Fragment as dialog in landscape.

Comment: I ended up displaying die existing ListFragment overlaying the Main-Fragment in a Frame-Layout. I looks quite nice in my opinion, a bit like this : http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-f_1A98GQ1fU/T0bzdWnYIOI/AAAAAAAAUmA/MuRnT7-YU28/s1600/export_06.png

Comment: Maybe this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516626/listfragment-as-dialogfragment/16430898#16430898

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What works for me is 
**1)** in xml layout for your DialogFragment called, let's say, **DialogFragmentwWithListFragment** specify ListFragment class
E.g. **dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment.xml** :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
             android:id="@+id/flContent"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:padding = "10dp"
             class="com.xxx.yyy.DialogFragmentwWithListFragment " />
</LinearLayout>
```

**2)** in **DialogFragmentwWithListFragment** inflate **dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment.xml**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, null);
}
```

**3)** invoke **DialogFragmentwWithListFragment**  as regular DialogFragment:

```
 DialogFragmentwWithListFragment dialogFragment = DialogFragmentwWithListFragment  .newInstance();
 dialogFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
 dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "tag");
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but what if you need to `setArguments()` when creating `DialogFragmentwWithListFragment` ??

Answer (score 3):

I would either put the `ListView` inside a `DialogFragment` or try to put the `ListFragment` inside a `Dialog`. I am not sure if the second one is possible though.

Comment: this blows up if I run it twice with: "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #6: Duplicate id 0x7f09007b, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment"

Answer (score 3):

You can show a list through a `DialogFragment` this way:(using the support v4 library)

```
public class MyListDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    onDlgListClick mCallback;

    private String[] lista;//the list you want to show with the dialog

    public static MyListDialogFragment newInstance(Bundle fB){
    MyListDialogFragment lstFrag = new MyListDialogFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putStringArray("lista", fB.getStringArray("lista"));//the list
        args.putString("titulo", fB.getString("titulo"));//the title of the list
        lstFrag.setArguments(args);

        return lstFrag;
    }

    public interface onDlgListClick{
        public void onLstItemSelected(String selection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (onDlgListClick) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement onLstItemSelected");
        }
        this.setCancelable(false);
    }

     @Override
     public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         lista = getArguments().getStringArray("lista");

         return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
         .setTitle(getArguments().getString("titulo"))
         .setCancelable(false)
         .setItems(lista, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){

                mCallback.onLstItemSelected(lista[item]);
                getDialog().dismiss(); //maybe you dont need these two lines
                MyListDialogFragment.this.dismiss();
            }
         }).create();
     }

}
```

On the main activity you extend `FragmentActivity` and implements the interface `MyListDialogFragment.onDlgListClick`

```
//the interface
@Override
public void onLstItemSelected(String selection) {//list dialog fragment interface
//do whatever you want
}

//calling the dialog
public void showFrags(int id){

        Bundle fB = new Bundle();

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("listdialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.commit();
        switch(id){
        case 0:
        fB.putStringArray("lista", list); fB.putString("titulo",title);
        MyListDialogFragment newListDlg = MyListDialogFragment.newInstance(fB);
        newListDlg.show(ft, "listdialog");
        break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Minimal implementation and others fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516626/listfragment-as-dialogfragment/16430898#16430898

Answer (score 1):

When adding a fragment inside another fragment, the documentation says you should do it dynamically (i.e., rather than hardcoding a `<fragment>` tag into your layout XML.

So here is how to do it dynamically. In this case, I add `MyListFragment` to `MyDialogFragment`:

**MyDialogFragment.java**

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = MyDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String ARG_TITLE = "ARG_TITLE";

    private EditText mEditText;

    public MyDialogFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
    }

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(String title) {
        MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_TITLE, title);
        myDialogFragment.setArguments(args);
        return myDialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            dialog.setTitle(args.getString(ARG_TITLE));
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        Dialog dialog = getDialog();
        dialog.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_selected_products, container, false);
        //addInnerFragment();

        Button okButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.okButton);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        dismiss();
                        //dismissAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                }
        );

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //addInnerFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        addInnerFragment();
    }

    public void addInnerFragment() {

        FragmentManager childFragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        //transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MyListFragment());
        transaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, MyListFragment.newInstance(MyListFragment.MODE_SELL));
        //transaction.commit();
        transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        childFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

    }

}
```

(As you will see, it also contains some functionality to set the title of the dialog.)

**dialog_fragment_selected_products.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyDialogFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/okButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="@string/ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Another advantage of doing it this way is that you can create an instance of the inner fragment in order to pass any arguments to it.

For completeness, here is the code that I use in my activity to show the DialogFragment:

**MyActivity.java**

```
private void showCurrentItemsDialog() {

    MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance("cpuk.org");
    //myDialogFragment.setRetainInstance(true);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(myDialogFragment, MyDialogFragment.TAG);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();

}
```