# Need Help calling ListFragment inside only part of a DialogFragment

Tags: android-studio, android-listfragment, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

So a question is asked here: [ListFragment as DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516626/listfragment-as-dialogfragment)

but what I need to know is how do I call a ListFragment inside of a DialogFragment *when it is not the only thing in the DialogFragment*.I cannot post a picture due to my reputation points so here is the xml layout of roughly what I want my fragment to have (e.g. list is only part of my fragment there's an edittext and button):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/person"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Name of First Person"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ScrubList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="201dp"
        android:padding = "10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add to Group"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
    style="@style/ButtonText"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to research this topic well before posting.