# Error inflating fragment in fragmentdialog

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment

I am trying to display an already created listviewfragment inside of a fragmentdialog. I used the answer from the question below to do it and it is not working.

[How to display an existing ListFragment in a DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342032/how-to-display-an-existing-listfragment-in-a-dialogfragment)

I am getting an `Error inflating class fragment` when I try to open the fragment dialog and the app crashes

Below is the `dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment` layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <fragment
         android:id="@+id/flContent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:padding = "10dp"
         class="com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.AndroidXMLParsingActivity" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and it is not the androidxmlparsingactivity fragment that is causing it to fail, I have tried it with other fragments and they did not work either

Below is my dialog fragment class

```
public class BodyDialogue extends DialogFragment {
int mNum;

/**
 * Create a new instance of MyDialogFragment, providing "num"
 * as an argument.
 */
static BodyDialogue newInstance(int num) {
    BodyDialogue f = new BodyDialogue();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");

    // Pick a style based on the num.
    int style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, theme = 0;
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 1: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 2: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 3: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_INPUT; break;
        case 4: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 5: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
        case 6: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE; break;
        case 7: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME; break;
        case 8: style = DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL; break;
    }
    switch ((mNum-1)%6) {
        case 4: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo; break;
        case 5: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog; break;
        case 6: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
        case 7: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Panel; break;
        case 8: theme = android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light; break;
    }
    setStyle(style, theme);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, null);

    return view;

}
}
```

and this is how i call the dialogfragment

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                BodyDialogue  dialogFragment = BodyDialogue.newInstance(1);
                 dialogFragment .setRetainInstance(true);
                 dialogFragment .show(getFragmentManager(), "bodydialogue");
            }
```

this was the cause in the logcat

```
08-17 19:43:15.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3605): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f0a0031, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.OptimusApps.stayhealthy.AndroidXMLParsingActivity
08-17 19:43:15.702: E/AndroidRuntime(3605):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
```

Comment: Did you try `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, container);`?

Comment: ... or even rather this `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, container, false);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use another View for every inflated fragment!

For example for the first inflate use:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, null);
```

And then use another name for the second inflate of the same layout:

```
View secondview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_with_list_fragment, null);
```